# Sending HTTP Post in Android

Tags: android

I'm struggling to find a way to send an HTTP POST in Android. I'm just looking to send a couple of parameters to a server.

There are many questions on StackOverflow, all with very similar answers, but many of the solutions are now deprecated.

A popular solution I've seen on here is:

```
public void postData() {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/yourscript.php");

    try {

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "123"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("string", "Hey"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // Catch Protocol Exception
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Catch IOException
    }
}
```

However, many the components here are now deprecated, such as HttpClient, HttpPost, and HttpResponse - so it can no longer be used.

Is there a new, equally simple way of doing this? Most of my research has pointed me towards Volley, but it seems unnecessarily complex for such a simple task.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use [HttpUrlConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html).

```
connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/)([github link](https://github.com/square/okhttp)), it's a very useful and convenient HTTP tool in android development.

Comment: Does okHttp work? From their website: _You can try out OkHttp without rewriting your network code. The okhttp-urlconnection module implements the familiar java.net.HttpURLConnection API and the okhttp-apache module implements the Apache HttpClient API._ Since the Apache HttpClient was the bit that was deprecated in my question, I'm just wondering if okHttp is still an option.

Comment: I've tried many times, it works for me perfectly. Using okhttp you can post `xml` or `json` to http server by very simple code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way i made a HTTP POST request:

```
private JSONObject doPostRequest(String url,
                                     Map<String, String> params) throws
            IOException, JSONException {

    HttpURLConnection con;
    StringBuilder postParam = new StringBuilder();
    for (String key : params.keySet()) {
        postParam.append(key).append("=").append(params.get(key)).append("&");
    }
    String urlParameters = postParam.toString();
    byte[] postData = urlParameters.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    int postDataLength = postData.length;

    URL toUrl = new URL(url);

    con = (HttpURLConnection) toUrl.openConnection();
    con.setConnectTimeout(TIME_OUT);
    con.setReadTimeout(TIME_OUT);
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    con.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postDataLength));

    OutputStream wr = con.getOutputStream();
    wr.write(postData);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    con.connect();

    InputStream in;
    try {
        in = con.getInputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        in = con.getErrorStream();
    }
    byte[] buffer = new byte[128];
    int lent;
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
    while ((lent = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        response.append(new String(buffer, 0, lent));
    }
    in.close();
    con.disconnect();

    return new JSONObject(response.toString());
}
```

I worked fine in my project. Hope it help you.

Comment: @Azarantara No you can't. You need create a separate thread to run it

Answer (score 0):

Volley Library makes this work quite easy and handles all other related tasks itself. 
Follow the link for how to acheive it: https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html